# Display an Activity while waiting for results to come back when using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I want an Activity to be displayed while downloading some information from the web.
When the information is done being downloaded, I want to show another activity.

This is my code:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);

    load();
}

private void load() {
    try {
        ArrayList data= new LoadPage().execute().get();
        if(data!= null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Pretty simple, but the problem I'm having is that this Activity is not shown on the screen (the UI). What happens is that the information gets downloaded and MainActivity is started as expected, but this activity (SplashScreenActivity) is never shown to the user.

Once inside MainActivity, if I press the "Back" button, I can see SplashScreenActivity.

I'm suspecting it's something to do with the UI thread and the fact that I'm calling the get method at `new LoadPage().execute().get();` and waiting for the results to come.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your not using the ASyncTask correctly. Calling the get method on the ASyncTask will block your UI Thread. The ASyncTask contains an onPostExecute method which is the right place to start an Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method in your `SplashScreenActivity`.

Once the `AsyncTask` in the background gets over the control shifts to `onPostExecute` method in which you can write the code for calling the next activity depending on your result.

Something like this:

```
   protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList data)
      {
        if(data!= null) 
        {
         Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(showContent);

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

We implemented this in a different way and it has worked nicely. The splash screen is a View and not a activity which is at the first position of a viewflipper. When the loading is done the splash sreen is dismissed with animation.